# Why are the JQuery methods I'm calling all giving "not a function" errors?

Tags: jquery, web, browser, console

I'm in the process of debugging a page (using Chrome web developer tools), and this page definitely has JQuery included as a library. For instance, when I enter the command $("#desktop-header"), I'm returned a Div object with the ID desktop-header. So I know it's there.

The problem is, any other JQuery method I try to call once I have that object, does NOT work.

$("#desktop-header")  ---> Returns div object with ID "desktop-header"

$("#desktop-header").html()  --->  "TypeError: $(...).html() is not a function"

$("#desktop-header").css("width")  --->   "TypeError: $(...).css() is not a function"
etc.

I read somewhere that this is because $(...) returns a DOM object, and those functions are for JQuery objects. But then when I look up how to get JQuery objects, they seem to be using the exact same code that I am, IE using $(...). I'm also finding plenty of examples online that are doing things like $("#div-id").html(), and they appear to be working fine. So why am I getting all these errors?

I'm very new to JQuery, so I apologize in advance if the answer is obvious. Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: What's `$("#desktop-header").constructor` result?

Comment: @raina77ow Cool function! It returns: HTMLDivElement() { [native code] }

So I guess this is a DOM object, and that's why the methods aren't working. Which leads me to the question of how can I get the jquery object equivalent so I can do things like look at the CSS programmatically. Every example I look up uses the $(...) method, which is the same that I'm using.

Comment: No chrome has `$` in it and it is NOT jQuery. So you are not using jQuery.

Comment: Hmmm...for starters, make sure you are correctly sourcing jQuery. Make sure it is sourced in your HTML before your javascript code. Then, when you run your code, try opening the console and typing `console.log(jQuery)` and see if it comes up with a function (correct) or undefined (incorrect).

Secondly, make sure to double check that the HTML element you are targeting is for sure an ID and not a class, since you are targeting an ID with the #. 

It might be useful to post a codepen or jsfiddle of what you got because a number of things could be going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome has shortcuts built in that happen to be `$` so just because there is a `$`, does not mean it is jQuery.

[Documentation do `$()` in Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/command-line/command-line-reference?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#selector)

> `$(selector)` returns the reference to the first DOM element with the specified CSS selector. This function is an alias for the `document.querySelector()` function.

Comment: Ah, that's what my confusion was. Thank you for clearing that up.